# How to add multiple addresses CC and BCC in MUTT?

Tags: mutt

The documentation is not very clear to me as sending an email adding multiple email address as BCC and CC.

Should I use:

`-b email@dom.com -b email2@dom.com`

or

`-b email1@dom.com email2@dom.com`

or should the emails be comma separated?

Answer (score 7):

Documentation (man page) says:

```
mutt [-nx] [-e cmd] [-F file] [-H file] [-i file] [-s subj] [-b addr] [-c addr] [-a file [...] --] addr|mailto_url [...]
```

which means that the complete `-c addr` switch must be repeated for each *Cc* recipient, and `-b addr` for each *Bcc* recipient.

The exception being the list of *To* recipients at the end of the command invocation, which need no switches.

Answer (score 3):

For any option of `mutt`:

`mutt [-nx] [-e cmd] [-F file] [-H file] [-i file] [-s subj] [-b addr] [-c addr] [-a file [...] --]`

if you have multiple arguments following, you can use quotation marks `"` and commas `,` to separate the individual commands within the same group. For example

`-e "set content_type=text/html, realname='John Citizen'"`

`-b "email1@dom.com, email2@dom.com"`

Full command:

`mutt -e "set content_type=text/html, realname='John Citizen'" -s "This is some subject" -- "this_is_the_email_you_want_to_send_to@recipients_email_address.com, second_persons_email@domain.com, third_persons_email@domain.com" < /home/dir/some_directory/the_HTML_file_you_want_to_send.html`